# Animating Sprites in Python

Tags: python

I am pretty new at coding, and am wondering how I would animate my sprite to look like it is actually moving. I think I have a general idea, but honestly I do not know where to start in my code to insert the different images and make it look like it's moving. This is my code, any tips are greatly appreciated.

```
SCREEN_SIZE = (1024, 768)
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from random import randint, choice
from Vector2 import Vector2

NEST_POSITION = (SCREEN_SIZE[0]/2, SCREEN_SIZE[1]/2)
NEST_POSITION_VECTOR2 = Vector2(NEST_POSITION)
ANT_COUNT = 20
NEST_SIZE = 100.

class State(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def do_actions(self):
    pass

  def check_conditions(self):
    pass

  def entry_actions(self):
    pass

  def exit_actions(self):
    pass


class StateMachine(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.states = {}
    self.active_state = None


  def add_state(self, state):
    self.states[state.name] = state


  def think(self):
    if self.active_state is None: return

    self.active_state.do_actions()
    new_state_name = self.active_state.check_conditions()
    if new_state_name is not None:
      self.set_state(new_state_name)


  def set_state(self, new_state_name):
    if self.active_state is not None:
      self.active_state.exit_actions()

    self.active_state = self.states[new_state_name]
    self.active_state.entry_actions()



class World(object):
  def __init__(self):

    self.entities = {}
    self.entity_id = 0
    self.background = pygame.surface.Surface(SCREEN_SIZE).convert()
    self.background.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.draw.circle(self.background, (200, 255, 200), NEST_POSITION, int(NEST_SIZE))

  def add_entity(self, entity):
    self.entities[self.entity_id] = entity
    entity.id = self.entity_id
    self.entity_id += 1

  def remove_entity(self, entity):
    del self.entities[entity.id]

  def get(self, entity_id):
    if entity_id in self.entities:
      return self.entities[entity_id]
    else:
      return None

  def process(self, time_passed):
    time_passed_seconds = time_passed / 1000.0
    for entity in self.entities.values():
      entity.process(time_passed_seconds)

  def render(self, surface):
    surface.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
    for entity in self.entities.itervalues():
      entity.render(surface)


  def get_close_entity(self, name, location, range=100.):
    for entity in self.entities.itervalues():
      if (entity.name == name):
        distance = location.get_distance_to(entity.location)
        if (distance < range):
          return entity
    return None

############################# GameEntity ####################################
## This is a "template" object - that is, we never actually create one of
## these objects in the game.
## This object is used as a base templet for other game objects that "extend"
## or "inherit from" this object.
## The leaf, Spider and And objects all extend the GameEntity object
class GameEntity(object):
  def __init__(self, world, name, image):

    self.world = world
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
    self.location = Vector2(0, 0)
    self.destination = Vector2(0, 0)
    self.speed = 0.

    self.brain = StateMachine()

    self.id = 0

  def render(self, surface):
    w, h = self.image.get_size()
    surface.blit(self.image, (self.location.x-w/2, self.location.y-h/2))

  def process(self, time_passed):
    self.brain.think()

    if ((self.speed > 0.) and (self.location != self.destination)):

      vec_to_destination = self.destination - self.location
      distance_to_destination = vec_to_destination.get_magnitude()
      heading = vec_to_destination.get_normalized()
      travel_distance = min(distance_to_destination, time_passed * self.speed)
      self.location += heading * travel_distance


############################# Leaf ##########################################
class Leaf(GameEntity):
  def __init__(self, world, image):
    GameEntity.__init__(self, world, "leaf", image)



############################# Ant ##########################################
class Spider(GameEntity):
  def __init__(self, world, image):
    GameEntity.__init__(self, world, "spider", image)
    self.dead_image = pygame.transform.flip(image, 0, 1)
    self.health = 25
    self.speed = 50. + randint(-20, 20)

  def bitten(self):
    self.health -= 1
    if (self.health <= 0):
      self.speed = 0.
      self.image = self.dead_image
    self.speed = 140.

  def render(self, surface):
    GameEntity.render(self, surface)

    w, h = self.image.get_size()
    bar_x = self.location.x - 12
    bar_y = self.location.y + h/2
    surface.fill( (255, 0, 0), (bar_x, bar_y, 25, 4))
    surface.fill( (0, 255, 0), (bar_x, bar_y, self.health, 4))

  def process(self, time_passed):
    if (self.location.x > SCREEN_SIZE[0] + 2):
      self.world.remove_entity(self)
      return

    GameEntity.process(self, time_passed)



############################# Ant ##########################################
class Ant(GameEntity):

  def __init__(self, world, image):
    GameEntity.__init__(self, world, "ant", image)

    exploring_state = AntStateExploring(self)
    seeking_state = AntStateSeeking(self)
    delivering_state = AntStateDelivering(self)
    hunting_state = AntStateHunting(self)

    self.brain.add_state(exploring_state)
    self.brain.add_state(seeking_state)
    self.brain.add_state(delivering_state)
    self.brain.add_state(hunting_state)

    self.carry_image = None

  def carry(self, image):
    self.carry_image = image

  def drop(self, surface):
    if self.carry_image:
      x = self.location.x
      y = self.location.y
      w, h = self.carry_image.get_size()
      surface.blit(self.carry_image, (x-w, y-h/2))
      self.carry_image = None

  def render(self, surface):
    GameEntity.render(self, surface)
    if (self.carry_image):
      x = self.location.x
      y = self.location.y
      w, h = self.carry_image.get_size()
      surface.blit(self.carry_image, (x-w, y-h/2))

############################# AntStateExploring #############################
class AntStateExploring(State):

  def __init__(self, ant):
    State.__init__(self, "exploring")
    self.ant = ant

  def random_destination(self):
    w, h = SCREEN_SIZE
    self.ant.destination = Vector2(randint(0, w), randint(0, h))

  def do_actions(self):
    if (randint(1, 20) == 1):
      self.random_destination()

  def check_conditions(self):
    leaf = self.ant.world.get_close_entity("leaf", self.ant.location)
    if (leaf is not None):
      self.ant.leaf_id = leaf.id
      return "seeking"

    spider = self.ant.world.get_close_entity("spider", NEST_POSITION_VECTOR2, NEST_SIZE)
    if (spider is not None):
      if (self.ant.location.get_distance_to(spider.location) < 100.):
        self.ant.spider_id = spider.id
        return "hunting"
    return None

  def entry_actions(self):
    self.ant.speed = 120. + randint(-30, 30)
    self.random_destination()

############################# AntStateSeeking ###############################
class AntStateSeeking(State):

  def __init__(self, ant):
    State.__init__(self, "seeking")
    self.ant = ant
    self.leaf_id = None

  def check_conditions(self):
    leaf = self.ant.world.get(self.ant.leaf_id)
    if (leaf is None): return "exploring"

    if (self.ant.location.get_distance_to(leaf.location) < 5.0):
      self.ant.carry(leaf.image)
      self.ant.world.remove_entity(leaf)
      return "delivering"

    return None

  def entry_actions(self):
    leaf = self.ant.world.get(self.ant.leaf_id)
    if (leaf is not None):
      self.ant.destination = leaf.location
      self.ant.speed = 160. + randint(-20, 20)

############################# AntStateDelivering ############################
class AntStateDelivering(State):

  def __init__(self, ant):
    State.__init__(self, "delivering")
    self.ant = ant


  def check_conditions(self):
    if (self.ant.location.get_distance_to(NEST_POSITION) < NEST_SIZE):
      if (randint(1, 10) == 1):
        self.ant.drop(self.ant.world.background)
        return "exploring"

    return None


  def entry_actions(self):
    self.ant.speed = 60.
    random_offset = Vector2(randint(-20, 20), randint(-20, 20))
    self.ant.destination = random_offset + NEST_POSITION



############################# AntStateHunting ###############################
class AntStateHunting(State):

  def __init__(self, ant):
    State.__init__(self, "hunting")
    self.ant = ant
    self.got_kill = False

  def do_actions(self):
    spider = self.ant.world.get(self.ant.spider_id)

    if (spider is None): return

    self.ant.destination = spider.location

    if (self.ant.location.get_distance_to(spider.location) < 15.):

      if (randint(1, 5) == 1):
        spider.bitten()

      if (spider.health <= 0):
        self.ant.carry(spider.image)
        self.ant.world.remove_entity(spider)
        self.got_kill = True


  def check_conditions(self):
    if (self.got_kill): return "delivering"

    spider = self.ant.world.get(self.ant.spider_id)

    if (spider is None): return "exploring"

    if (spider.location.get_distance_to(NEST_POSITION) > NEST_SIZE * 3):
      return "exploring"

    return None

  def entry_actions(self):
    self.speed = 160. + randint(0, 50)

  def exit_actions(self):
    self.got_kill = False





############################# Set up Game ###############################
def run():
  pygame.init()
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)
  pygame.display.set_caption("The Super Amazing Ant Simulation")

  world = World()

  w, h = SCREEN_SIZE

  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

  ant_image = pygame.image.load("ant.png").convert_alpha()
  ant2_image = pygame.image.load("ant6.gif").convert_alpha()
  ant3_image = pygame.image.load("ant7.gif").convert_alpha()
  leaf_image = pygame.image.load("leaf.png").convert_alpha()
  spider_image = pygame.image.load("spider.png").convert_alpha()

  ############# Place ants in starting locations #########################
  for ant_no in xrange(ANT_COUNT):
    ant = Ant(world, ant_image)
    ant.location = Vector2(randint(0, w), randint(0, h))
    ant.brain.set_state("exploring")
    world.add_entity(ant)

  ############################# Game Loop ###############################

  while (True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if (event.type == QUIT):
        pygame.quit()
        return

    time_passed = clock.tick(30)

    if (randint(1, 50) == 1):
      leafX = randint(0, w)
      leafY = randint(0, h)
      numberOfLeafs = randint(5,25)
      for leafNumber in range(numberOfLeafs):
        leaf = Leaf(world, leaf_image)
        leaf.location = Vector2(leafX, leafY)
        world.add_entity(leaf)


    if (randint(1, 100) == 1):
      spider = Spider(world, spider_image)
      spider.location = Vector2(-50, randint(0, h))
      spider.destination = Vector2(w+50, randint(0, h))
      world.add_entity(spider)

    world.process(time_passed)
    world.render(screen)

    pygame.display.update()


############################# Call run to start game #########################
try:
  if (Vector2.version() != "Version 2014-04-09"):
    raise()
except:
  print "****ERROR**** Vector2 version mis-matched with AntSimulation.py"
  sys.exit()

run()
```

Comment: You will have to trim that book to article-size piece of code, leave in only the relevant bits, and explain why do you think it's not doing what it is supposed to do

Comment: @Puciek I imagine the main problem he has with his code is that it's displaying a static image for each entity rather than an animated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pygame, an animation is just multiple images played in a sequence.  I'm assuming that because you are wanting to animate a sprite you already have an image sequence in mind to use.

Here is a basic example of an animation class (you will probably want to add quite a bit of functionality to this):

```
class Animation(object):
    def __init__(self, image_list):
        self.image_list = image_list  #a list of pygame images
        self.total_frames = len(image_list)
        self.index = 0
    def next(self):
        image = self.image_list[self.index]
        self.index = (self.index+1) % self.total_frames  #loops back around
        return image
```

Now, in your sprite class, when you are ready to switch to the next frame of your animation:

```
self.image = my_animation.next()
```